Saving XML string to SQL Server table
In SSIS (Visual Studio) Script task, I am trying to ignore XML namespaces and trying to convert XML data and write it to a SQL Server table. Here is the XML data its being fed through a variable. It does go into the loop. I have tried going the XPATH route but same issue. Should I try XML reader? Please help, XML is attached.
public void Main ()
{
    String xmlData = (string)Dts.Variable["User::vXmlResponse"].Value;
    xDocument xDoc =  Xdocument.Parse(xmlData);

    Xnamespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
    Xnamespace abc = "https://Ies.aa.com/";

    var packages = xDoc.Descendants (soap + "Body").Descaendants(abc + "Packages").Descendants(abc + "Package");

    String connectionString = "xxxxxxxxx";

    using (sqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        foreach (var package in packages)
        {
            String packageName = vessel.Element(abc + "PACKAGE_NM")?.Value.Trim();
            int packageImo = int.Parse(package.Element(abc + "PACKAGE_IMO")?.Value.Trim());
            DateTimeOffset gmtDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(package.Element(abc + "GMT_DATE_TIME")?.Value.Trim());

            string query = "Insert command";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand (query, connection))
            {
                command.parameters.AddWithValue ("@packageName",packageName);
                command.parameters.AddWithValue ("@packageIMO",packageIMO);
                command.parameters.AddWithValue ("@GMTDateTime",GMTDateTime);

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    Dts.taskresult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}

XML:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns: soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmIns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xMISchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <Wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-189039"> 
            <wsu: Created>2024-08-29718:31:59.2502</wsu: Created> 
            <wsu:Expires>2024-08-29T18:36:59.2502</wsu:Expires> 
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security> 
</soap:Header> 
<soap:Body> 
<GetIntransitPackagesResponse xmlns="https://Ies.aa.com/"> 
<GetIntransitPackagesResult> 
<Packages xmIns=""> 
    <PACKAGE> 
        <PACKAGE_NM>SUB HALI</PACKAGE_NM> 
        <PACKAGE_IMO>886300</PACKAGE_IMO> 
        <GMT_DATE_TIME>2024-08-2918: 14:18-05: 00</GMT_DATE_TIME>
     </PACKAGE> 
     <PACKAGE> 
         <PACKAGE_NM>KSAFKIS KLO</PACKAGE_NM> 
         <PACKAGE_IMO>112826</PACKAGE_IMO> 
         <GMT_DATE_TIME >2024-08-29T17: 59:50-05:00</GMT_DATE_TIME> 
     </PACKAGE> 
 </Packages>
 </GetIntransitPackagesResult>
 </GetIntransitPackagesResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>

I have tried using Xpath but have not had success with XDocument or Xpath.

Why do you want to do this?  Removing namespaces deletes important validation data.  Too many people create invalid XML because schema checks are not done and then users get errors because the schema check fails.

It is better to use SSIS Execute SQL Task and pass the entire XML as a single parameter to a stored procedure. That stored procedure will shred XML parameter and insert data into a target table as a single statement without any loops

What is your target database?

@YitzhakKhabinsky: Target database is a SQL Server.

If you are up to it, I can post an answer with a stored procedure. That's the ETL way. Just let me know

@jdweng Is Xpath a better way to do it? or XMLReader?

@YitzhakKhabinsky  Yes please, thank you. I will try if it nothing else works.

Please edit your question, and provide a well-formed XML.

Failing to format your code in a reasonable way shows disrepect to those who might help you. You will have better results taking the minimal effort  to use decent indentation and correct keyword and variable capitalization, so it least has a chance to compile.

If file is huge, then you must use XmlReader.

It is better to use SSIS Execute SQL Task and pass the entire XML as a single parameter to a stored procedure. That stored procedure will shred XML parameter and insert data into a target table as a single statement without any loops as a set based operation.
That's the ETL way. No need in any SSIS Script Task.
I took the liberty to fix the provided XML, and made it well-formed.
Below is T-SQL for a MS SQL Server stored procedure.
T-SQL #1
Just to see and feel it
    DECLARE @xmlParam XML = 
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/xMISchema"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soap:Header>
            <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                           soap:mustUnderstand="1">
                <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
                               wsu:Id="Timestamp-189039">
                    <wsu:Created>2024-08-29718:31:59.2502</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires>2024-08-29T18:36:59.2502</wsu:Expires>
                </wsu:Timestamp>
            </wsse:Security>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <GetIntransitPackagesResponse xmlns="https://Ies.aa.com/">
                <GetIntransitPackagesResult>
                    <Packages xmIns="">
                        <PACKAGE>
                            <PACKAGE_NM>SUB HALI</PACKAGE_NM>
                            <PACKAGE_IMO>886300</PACKAGE_IMO>
                            <GMT_DATE_TIME>2024-08-29T18:14:18-05:00</GMT_DATE_TIME>
                        </PACKAGE>
                        <PACKAGE>
                            <PACKAGE_NM>KSAFKIS KLO</PACKAGE_NM>
                            <PACKAGE_IMO>112826</PACKAGE_IMO>
                            <GMT_DATE_TIME>2024-08-29T17:59:50-05:00</GMT_DATE_TIME>
                        </PACKAGE>
                    </Packages>
                </GetIntransitPackagesResult>
            </GetIntransitPackagesResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>';
    
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS ns1
        , DEFAULT 'https://Ies.aa.com/')
    -- INSERT INTO tbl_target (PACKAGE_NM, PACKAGE_IMO, GMT_DATE_TIME) -- uncomment this line when you are ready
    SELECT x.value('(PACKAGE_NM/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS PACKAGE_NM
        , x.value('(PACKAGE_IMO/text())[1]', 'INT') AS PACKAGE_IMO
        , x.value('(GMT_DATE_TIME/text())[1]', 'DATETIMEOFFSET(0)') AS GMT_DATE_TIME
    FROM @xmlParam.nodes('/ns1:Envelope/ns1:Body/GetIntransitPackagesResponse/GetIntransitPackagesResult/Packages/PACKAGE') AS t(x);

Output



PACKAGE_NM
PACKAGE_IMO
GMT_DATE_TIME




SUB HALI
886300
2024-08-29 18:14:18 -05:00


KSAFKIS KLO
112826
2024-08-29 17:59:50 -05:00



SQL #2
Real deal.
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_myProcedure
(
    @xmlParam XML
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS ns1
        , DEFAULT 'https://Ies.aa.com/')
    -- INSERT INTO tbl_target (PACKAGE_NM, PACKAGE_IMO, GMT_DATE_TIME) -- uncomment this line when you are ready
    SELECT x.value('(PACKAGE_NM/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS PACKAGE_NM
        , x.value('(PACKAGE_IMO/text())[1]', 'INT') AS PACKAGE_IMO
        , x.value('(GMT_DATE_TIME/text())[1]', 'DATETIMEOFFSET(0)') AS GMT_DATE_TIME
    FROM @xmlParam.nodes('/ns1:Envelope/ns1:Body/GetIntransitPackagesResponse/GetIntransitPackagesResult/Packages/PACKAGE') AS t(x);
END


As I see, you struggle with getting information out of XML. In .NET there's XDocument class to help working with XMLs (also there's XmlDocument class, but IMO it's less convenient in this case. Here's the example:
var xmlRaw = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""> 
<soap:Header>
</soap:Header> 
<soap:Body> 
<GetIntransitPackagesResponse> 
<GetIntransitPackagesResult> 
<Packages> 
    <PACKAGE> 
        <PACKAGE_NM>SUB HALI</PACKAGE_NM> 
        <PACKAGE_IMO>886300</PACKAGE_IMO> 
        <GMT_DATE_TIME>2024-08-2918: 14:18-05: 00</GMT_DATE_TIME>
     </PACKAGE> 
     <PACKAGE> 
         <PACKAGE_NM>KSAFKIS KLO</PACKAGE_NM> 
         <PACKAGE_IMO>112826</PACKAGE_IMO> 
         <GMT_DATE_TIME>2024-08-29T17: 59:50-05:00</GMT_DATE_TIME> 
     </PACKAGE> 
 </Packages>
 </GetIntransitPackagesResult>
 </GetIntransitPackagesResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>";

// If you have file with XML, use XDocument.Load(path) method.
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlRaw);

// Here you can simplify to xDoc.Descendants("PACKAGE");
// But i prefer this way to have less ambigous search
// (you define what is expected tree).
var packages = xDoc.Descendants("Packages").Descendants("PACKAGE");

foreach (var package in packages)
{
    // And just get needed information from the node.
    var packageName = package.Descendants("PACKAGE_NM").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

    var packageImo = package.Descendants("PACKAGE_IMO").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

    Console.WriteLine(packageName + " " + packageImo);
}


The OP environment is SSIS. There is no need to use c# in SSIS to insert data into a database. It is not a c# exercise
